# androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException but view can be found in View Hierarchy?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

The android espresso testing framework claims there is no matching view, but the view can be found in the View Hierachy that is also printed together with the exception. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong or give me a clue where to look? Thanks a lot.

This is my matcher code:

```
onView(
   allOf(
       withId(R.id.message),
       withText(R.string.feedback_pin_blocked),
       withParent(withId(R.id.user_feedback))
   )
).check(matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
```

This is the exception with the view hierarchy:

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (view.getId() is <2131296583/**************:id/message> and an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() equals string from resource id: <2131820672> [feedback_pin_blocked] value: Your PIN has been blocked. and view.getParent() view.getId() is <2131296829>)

View Hierarchy [relevant part]:
+------->LinearLayout{id=2131296829, res-name=user_feedback, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=155, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=182.0, child-count=3} 
|
+-------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131296583, res-name=message, visibility=VISIBLE, width=611, height=67, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=44.0, y=44.0, text=Your PIN has been blocked., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
```